# Replace Created By with Custom Column

Tags: workflow, blog

In my Intranet site (SP2016) I am currently using blog posts for news articles.

I have a workflow form subsite to create post at top level Posts list - using the workflow, loses the information of the original poster.

I have created an additional field which will hold the original posters information.

What is the best and/or easiest way to remove the 'Created By' on /posts.aspx page with my 'Author' field?

Thanks in advance for any support given.

Edit: I have tried changing the Fieldref in Posts.aspx already from the created by field to my new field - but error [object Object] is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this this way? 
There is better solution and that you create column: PublishedOnRoot - Yes/No and use Search Query WebPart, where you will querying all posts from the whole intranet and filtered them only for PublishedOnRoot - 1(Yes) and you have all information from the base included the CreatedBy.

*And if you start writing some discussion under these posts, you have two different posts the source and the root and you have two discussions cause there are two separate threats... This is bad solution...*

Comment: Thank you for your response....

I have one main news list at the top of the site....

I have many sub sites below the top site....

Each sub site has the ability to create news either for their own audience limited by permissions on sub site) or they have the ability to send news to the main list (top site) from their own subsite.

There will not be 2 instances of each news item, and thus no separate threads.